# How to POST data continuously in background from android activity to PHP server?

Tags: android, sqlite, service, background

I am new to android development and trying to make a basic chatting application (like WhatsApp but basic). I currently using Async task to send message data from app to webservice. But the problem is whenever I send some message it takes too long to send the data. Also in that time if user navigate to another activity or send another message then previous request in interrupted.
I read somewhere that i have to first save the data in SQLITE database and then use Background service and **POST** method to send the messages data and get the response from webservice. But I am not sure that it is the best way to do that and as I am new I dont have much idea on how to implement this.

Currently I am using **GET** method with Async Task and this is how my URL looks like.

```
String URI = "localhost/sendmsg.php?user=" + recId + "&message=" + text +"&authKey=" + authKey;
```

So basically i want to send 3 fields: recId,text,authkey.

Can someone please help me with any tutorial or code to implement this.Thanks